# C++ template is slower than equivalent C macro, why?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, macros

In my program, I have the need to iterate through a circular list implemented as an array quickly. The slow part of the loop happens to be the remainder operation (division!) that is required to ensure that the index doesn't fall off the far end of the array. Thus, I cleverly split the looping into three parts to avoid the remainder operation.

To reduce code duplication, I have created a C macro and a C++ template for the looping construct shown below:

```
template <typename F>
static inline void
for_loop_pairs(int at, int loops, const F fun) {
    int right = MIN(loops, N - at - 1);
    int left = loops - right;
    while (right) {
        int next = at + 1;
        fun(at, next);
        at = next;
        next++;
        right--;
    }
    if (left) {
        fun(N - 1, 0);
        left--;
        at = 0;
        while (left) {
            int next = at + 1;
            fun(at, next);
            at = next;
            next++;
            left--;
        }
    }
}

#define FOR_LOOP_PAIRS(at, loops, fun)  \
    int right = MIN(loops, N - at - 1); \
    int left = loops - right;           \
    int k0 = at;                        \
    while (right) {                     \
        int k1 = k0 + 1;                \
        fun;                            \
        k0 = k1;                        \
        k1++;                           \
        right--;                        \
    }                                   \
    if (left) {                         \
        k0 = N - 1;                     \
        int k1 = 0;                     \
        fun;                            \
        left--;                         \
        k0 = 0;                         \
        while (left) {                  \
            k1 = k0 + 1;                \
            fun;                        \
            k0 = k1;                    \
            k1++;                       \
            left--;                     \
        }                               \
    }
```

`N` is the numer of items in the array. To call the macro and the for-loop I use:

```
FOR_LOOP_PAIRS(start, loops, {
    // Do stuff with k0 and k1, which are the indices.
});
for_loop_pairs(start, loops, [&](int k0, int k1) {
    // Do stuff with k0 and k1 which are the indices.
});
```

The version using templates is much cleaner but also 5% slower which is unacceptable. My question is what am I doing wrong? I would expect the template code to produce exactly the same code as the macro.

Compile command: `g++ -Wall -Werror -fPIC -march=native -mtune=native -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer fname.cpp` gcc version 7.4.0.

Comment: Can you give your compile command?

Comment: I think that there would be different code produced,  cause the macro duplicates and inlines the code while the template uses a lambda function that results in function calls. The inline keyword is only a hint for the compiler.

Comment: GCC *should* be able to figure out that the lambdas should be inlined. If it doesn't figure that out, I want to know what the trick is to make sure it does.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Could fill out the `// Do stuff ...` parts and surrounding code with an example, so that we can benchmark ourselves? In particular inlining may be affected by the contents of the lambda.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist sorry, I mixed two things up. The inline thing has nothing do to with the lambda. Ignore the my second sentence.

Comment: Godbolt is your friend. Also don't try to outthink the c++ compiler

Comment: No, this is still likely an apples versus oranges comparison. Inline code versus a lambda function call. And, to make things even worse, the lambda captures some unspecified objects by reference. More overhead. This question is defective, and fails to include all relevant information, and does not meet the requirements for a [mre]; as such no authoritative answer will be possible.

Comment: @uneven_mark unfortunately I cannot share that code... It mutates the context hence the `&` in the lambda declaration. I cannot produce an mwe either because then the problem goes away.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can you tell me **why** it is apples to oranges? My understanding of C++ (as implemented by modern compilers) is that I'm right to expect the template version to generate exactly the same code as the macro version.

Comment: Could you share a minimally reproducible example? I want to see if fun can be inlined in each instance.

Comment: I already explained which parts are apples "inline, macro-expanded code", and which parts are oranges "some unknown lambda, that captures some unknown number of objects by reference and does something unknown". Although you have the right to expect compilers to implement simple optimizations, you have very little expectation of compilers always making every kind of optimization that appears to be obvious to a carbon-based life form.

Comment: There isn't really any way to help without being able to have a look at the generated assembly, but if inlining is really the problem, you may want to try putting gcc's `always_inline` attribute on the lambda, but I am unsure right now what the correct syntax for it is. I think `[&](int k0, int k1)[[gnu::always_inline]]{`.

Comment: If the problem goes away when you produce a mwe then it is probably because your example fun is easily inlined, your actual fun is not. There are competing interests, keeping the executable small and making it fast for example. You could try __attribute__((always_inline))

Comment: 5% slower unacceptable? Are you serious. For 99.999% of the application, it won't matters and if it does matters, you would also simplify your code for example by using a single argument callback. Also, the macro version is not equivalent to the function version because `at` is passed by "reference" in one case and by value on the other case so change made from the macro or function might not have same effect on caller data. As already pointed out, without reproductible MSVE, your question is almost pointless. If you want to know why it is slower, then we need all data to be able to analyse it

Comment: `[&k0, &k1 /* other variable here */](){ /* code here */ }` would also be more equivalent to the macro version that update caller variables. ** You need to give us all required code**. It is much easier for you to understand why you don't get the expected result because you have all the required code to reproduce the problem! If while making the MCVE the problem disappears, then the line you removed when the problem goes away might give a clue. Or there might be a threshold when the compiler decide to inline or not the code. **Obviously, that information is required to be in the question**.